# How to call a javascript function from a page loaded through a WebRequest object

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm loading a page from code behind in C# using this code:

```
WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/dostuff.aspx");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
```

Inside dostuff.aspx, I have javascript function that I need to call after some processing.  Basically, the problem I have is how to execute #3 since my page is in the WebRequest object.

1. Load the page through WebRequest
2. Execute some code to populate an element
3. Call the javascript function which uses the value on the element in #2
4. End

Appreciate any insight.

Comment: You'll need to look into how to scrape single page applications.

Comment: You cannot execute Javascript with those objects, they can simpley make  a request and receive a response. To execute Javascript you need to parse the response and use a javascript engine look int CefSharp which allows you to use the Chromium engine inside C# applications. Then load the response received from that page and then you can execute Javascript.